# Rotate a node but not its content: the case of the ellipse decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf

**What I want to do:** Draw a node decorated with bumps, but with the decoration starting from the right (ie, opposite to the usual) of the node.

**Why I want to do it:** I will have a node *hiding* the part of the bumps that connects weirdly, but I want to be able to *chose* where this connection is made.  Luckily, I only need "left of the node" and "right of the node".

**What I thought was the solution:** I thought I could use `shape border rotate`, so that only the *border* would be rotated.  Define:

```
  \newcommand{\drawprost}[2][Prost!]{
    \node [draw,
           decorate,decoration={bumps,mirror},
           #2,
           postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
                        {\arrow[line width=5pt,blue]{>}}}}]
          {#1};}
```

Now the following two commands work as expected:

```
  \drawprost{shape=trapezium,shape border rotate=180}
  \drawprost{shape=trapezium,shape border rotate=0}
```

with the ugly blue arrow being rotated 180 degrees in the second drawing.  But without `shape=trapezium` or with `shape=ellipse`, this fails miserably.

**An ugly solution:**  The only solution I came up with is (using `ellipse`, otherwise I don't even have a solution):

```
  \drawprost[\phantom{Prost!}]{rotate=180,shape=ellipse,label=center:Prost!}
```

that is, `phantom`ing the label, and redrawing it.

**Question:** Is there a better way to do it?  Bonus point for a method that would shift the start of the decoration (rotate) at any given point :-)

---

**Full code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\drawprost}[2][Prost!]{
    \node [draw,
           decorate,decoration={bumps,mirror},
           #2,
           postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
                        {\arrow[line width=5pt,blue]{>}}}}]
          {#1};}

  \newlength\yshift
  % I get the expected result only with trapezium.
  \foreach \shape in {,shape=trapezium,shape=ellipse}
    \foreach \rotate in {0, 180}
    {
      \expandafter\drawprost\expandafter{%
        \shape,yshift=\yshift,shape border rotate=\rotate};
      \global\advance\yshift -2cm
    }

  % What I do want:
  \drawprost[\phantom{Prost!}]{yshift=\yshift,rotate=180,shape=ellipse,label=center:Prost!}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try the options `shift only` , `pre` and `post` stated in the manual for decorations?

Comment: To the extent of my knowledge, I did.  Am I missing something?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Sorry for my comment. That did not make too much sense. I was able to compile after some guessing, but I don't understand what I am seeing. What is the blue arrow and what should it look like? And if possible can you put a picture of what you want to achieve. It is kind of difficult to guess now.

Comment: Sorry for my imprecision.  I've added the full code.  What I want is the last drawing, but without `\phantom`ing.  Thanks!

Comment: I would expect `mark=at position 0.5` to work... This gives a `dimension too large` error though. Don't quite understand why.

Comment: I have two interpretations of what you're asking for and I'm not sure which is right.  Imagine that instead of 0 or 180, you specified an angle of 45.  Would you want the ellipse to lie along the x=y and x=-y axes or would you want the standard ellipse but drawn *starting* at the intersection with the x=y line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source of the difficulty is that ellipses are constructed in a particular way in TikZ.  They are paths that start from the x-axis and proceed counter-clockwise around their centre.  The vast majority of the time, the exact parametrisation doesn't matter.  You appear to have found the one situation where it does!

In the actual question, you only want to be able to mirror the ellipse, and so draw it starting from the negative x-axis (the title of the question suggests a more flexible approach).  That's actually not too hard since we can exploit the symmetry of the ellipse.  The key is to provide it with a negative x-radius, since then it will start from the negative x-axis (and proceed clockwise, but we could correct for that by negating the y-radius as well).  To do this, we interrupt the call from the node shape to the drawing command and flip the sign of the x-radius.  The simplest way to do this is to redefine the `\pgfpathellipse` macro to do the negation and then call the original macro.  The following code does this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,decorations.markings}
\makeatletter
\let\origpgfpathellipse=\pgfpathellipse
\def\revpgfpathellipse#1#2#3{%
  #2%
  \pgf@xa=-\pgf@x
  \origpgfpathellipse{#1}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{0pt}}{#3}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{
  reversed ellipse/.style={
    ellipse,
    reverse the ellipse%
  },
  reverse the ellipse/.code={
    \let\pgfpathellipse=\revpgfpathellipse
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ellipse,
  draw,
  postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {
        \arrow[line width=5pt,blue]{>}
      }
    }
  }
] at (0,0) {hello world};

\node[reversed ellipse,
  draw,
  postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {
        \arrow[line width=5pt,blue]{>}
      }
    }
  }
] at (0,-2) {hello world};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: rotated ellipse]

(the arrow got clipped, but you can see where it lies)

Answer (score 3):

You could move the label to be part of the macro and then specifying the `\phantom` within the macro allows the width of the node to be computed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\drawprost}[2][Prost!]{
    \node [draw,
           decorate,decoration={bumps,mirror},
           #2, label=center:#1,
           postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
                        {\arrow[line width=5pt,blue]{>}}}}]
          {\phantom{#1}};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \drawprost[Prost!]{rotate=180,shape=ellipse}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear on my request: I want to avoid using `phantom`.  I have the feeling that there is a TikZ way to do it, rather than this hack: In fact, I don't gather why it works with `trapezium` and not with `ellipse`, and think I'm missing something.

Comment: @Michaël Well, the manual states "Some shapes (but not all), support a special kind of rotation. This rotation affects only the border of a
shape and is independent of the node contents, but in addition to any other transformations." `ellipse` is problably on of the shapes for which it doesn't work, but I couldn't find a list of shapes for which it does.